# How to make a pop up?

Tags: html

I'm just wondering how something like [this](http://puu.sh/kSKqo/5794b48141.jpg) is done 
I searched on google but I only found informations about ad pop ups

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's often called a "modal div".

Comment: try reading this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_dialog_showmodal.asp

Answer (score 0):

There you go,

```
<h1>Popup without JavaScript</h1>
    <div class="box">
        <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
    </div>

    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Here i am</h2>
            <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
            <div class="content">
                Thanks for pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


**CSS**


    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background: url(4.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: orange;
      margin: 100px 0;
    }

    .box {
      width: 20%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
      padding: 35px;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 20px/50px;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .button {
      font-size: 1em;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      border-radius: 20px/50px;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    .button:hover {
      background: orange;
    }

    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      transition: opacity 500ms;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .overlay:target {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .popup {
      margin: 70px auto;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 30%;
      position: relative;
      transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .popup h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
      color: #333;
      font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .popup .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      right: 30px;
      transition: all 200ms;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333;
    }
    .popup .close:hover {
      color: orange;
    }
    .popup .content {
      max-height: 30%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Anytime.Help community by checking the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below:

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(220,220,220, .5);
}

.modal{
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
p{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='modal'>Modal window</div>
</div>
<p> other content</p>
```

Try with absolute positioned container div and a child div with actual content. I added paragraph with content *Other content* to illustrate the effect